# Making package-private service in Android accessible to classes under different package

Tags: java, android

I literally copied and pasted `LocationUpdatesService.java` and `Utils.java` from [Android Location-Samples github here](https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice) to my project but instead of putting those 2 files in the same package/folder as my other files who will be using them, I put them inside another sub package from the classes that will be accessing them. Specifically, I put them inside `com.company.project.helpers` and my other classes that will be accessing them are inside `com.company.project.view.ui` for example.

Below is the portion of my code that's accessing `LocationUpdatesService.java`:

```
private val mServiceConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        val binder: LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder = service as LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder
        mService = binder.getService()
        mBound = true
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
        mService = null
        mBound = false
    }
}
```

But I got this error `Cannot access 'getService': it is package-private in 'Local Binder'` at this line `mService = binder.getService()`.

So how do I make `LocationUpdatesService.java` accessible to codes from other/neighbour packages? I have tried removing any `private` identifier inside `LocationUpdatesService.java` and replace it with `public` and added `public' identifier to functions inside`LocationUpdatesService.java` that doesn't have any identifier but the error message still appears.

Comment: Did you add `public` to `LocationUpdatesService getService()` in the inner class `LocalBinder`? That should do it, really.

Comment: Let me take a moment to facepalm myself first. Then let me say thanks. I will now close this question.

Comment: No worries. :) As a side note, if you don't want to modify the original source code, you could put a "proxy class" in the same package. This would just delegate the calls you want to do. No need to change the package visible methods then.